# X forwarding freeze after source server is restarted by watchdog

Tags: ssh, centos, qt, xforwarding

I am currently working on an issue with the Xforwarding of a QT application over lan.

Our source server is forwarding the interface of our application using the command "screen -dm" to a client computer.

When the source server is stopped by an itco watchdog ( triggered by a crash of an application process), the interface displayed on the client stays frozen.

Is there a clean way to setup the xforwarding so that the client interface disappear when the source reboots ?
(creating a daemon on the client for the sole purpose of pinging the peer and closing a window seemed quite ugly.)

All solutions are good, with the exception of an OS version upgrade (Customer requirement).

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S :You can find below all the settings that can help ( and that i tried to tinker to make it work)

Env: CentOS 6.5, qt-4.6.2

App display parameters :

```
/home/user/bin/qapp config.xml -geometry +0+0 -display 192.168.1.100:0.0 Read-Write
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config :

```
Host *
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ServerAliveInterval 5
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```